# Ignition RemoteImageView gives "Failed creating disk cache directory" warning

Tags: android, droid-fu

I am using Ignition (formerly known as DroidFu) to download images in the background and update related ImageViews when they are ready. I also wanted the images to be cached, so they would not have to be re-downloaded every time the user revisited that Activity. I noticed these errors in the log:

```
06-06 12:28:10.254: W/Droid-Fu[CacheFu](7567): Failed creating disk cache directory /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/my.package.name/cache/cachefu/image_cache
06-06 12:28:10.489: W/Droid-Fu[CacheFu](7567): Failed creating disk cache directory /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/my.package.name/cache/cachefu/image_cache
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered the directory for my package was not being created in Android/data on the SD card. I needed to add the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to my AndroidManifest.xml; since I didn't need this elsewhere in the app, I had no idea I needed it for using RemoteImageViews and RemoteImageLoaders.